# Using git without (or with limited) revision history?

Tags: git, revision, dropbox

I was searching for dropbox alternatives with own server, but had no luck. iFolder was pretty nice, but currently iFolder server could only be installed on linux. I have only Windows server now. (I tried syncrify, but it didn't work well as I expected)

So after hours of searching, I gave up and determined to use git or subversion as a dropbox alternative.

But I'm worrying about disk space that git repos will eat up with binary changes.

**Is there a way to keep git repository from storing revision history or any other good approach for this problem?**

Comment: This might be better suited to superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll want to look at something other than revision control systems if you're concerned about history.

The whole point of revision control systems is maintaining a history of changes, so you can't really turn that off.